# Field extension question

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

A question I recall from Carl Linderholm's "Mathematics Made Difficult", Chapter 3 Exercise 8.

```
A farmer acquires and algebraically closed field by extending his field finitely. 
What can be said about the original field?
```

What can be said? I immediately see two fields with this property, ${\Bbb R}$, and $\overline{\Bbb Q}\cap {\Bbb R}$. Is this it? or is there a better characterization? Do these fields have to contain ${\Bbb Q}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was asked and answered [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8756/examples-of-algebraic-closures-of-finite-index) before. The examples you give are essentially it, in the sense that the field has to be [real closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) and the algebraic closure is obtained by adding a square root of -1. This is the Artin-Schreier theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard of MO before.